# Axios and Vue won't make an api call to my server , due to a cors policy issue

Tags: express, vue.js, cors, axios

I have my cors setup in my express(Node) server like this:

```
server.options('*',cors());
server.use(cors());
```

and making the call on my Vue website like this

```
axios.default
          .post(url, {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            email: this.email,
            interests: this.interests,
            targetURL: "https://www.joinvurchase.com/email-verified/",
            poolID
          })
```

But I get the following error:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I think the cors on my server is setup correctly because when I make a call using postman it works and returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*` header. Also when I make a call on my website, it errors out almost instantly. So it may not even making it to my server. The exact same setup works when tested locally. The issue is present after both the server and the website are deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I use google domains and I had a domain re-rout from "mydomain.com" to "www.mydomain.com". assuming this would work, I used my url as mydomain.com. Since these calls ended up getting rerouted, my calls were failing with `Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.` . So i simply started adding www to my urls and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this, this solves cors issue for me

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```